# Implementing splay() method for Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, loops, rotation, infinite

I am trying to implement a splay(Node x) method for a Binary Search Tree. I have the leftRotation(Node x) and rightRotation(Node x) methods implemented correctly (atleast, I think they are...), but when I try to implement them in a splay(Node x) method, it calls itself in an infinite loop. Now, I know why it's doing that, but can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Here is the leftRotation(Node x) method:

```
public void leftRotation(Node<E> x) {
    if (x.getRightChild() == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node<E> y = x.getRightChild();
    x.setRightChild(y.getLeftChild());

    if (y.getLeftChild() != null) {
        y.getLeftChild().setParent(x);
    }

    y.setParent(x.getParent());

    if (x.getParent() == null) {
        root = y;
    } else {
        if (x == x.getParent().getLeftChild()) {
            x.getParent().setLeftChild(y);
        } else {
            x.getParent().setRightChild(y);
        }
    }

    y.setLeftChild(x);
    x.setParent(y);
}
```

Here's the rightRotation(Node x) method:

```
public void rightRotation(Node<E> x) {
    if (x.getLeftChild() == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node<E> y = x.getLeftChild();
    x.setRightChild(y.getRightChild());

    if (y.getRightChild() != null) {
        y.getRightChild().setParent(x);
    }

    y.setParent(x.getParent());

    if (x.getParent() == null) {
        root = y;
    } else {
        if (x == x.getParent().getRightChild()) {
            x.getParent().setRightChild(y);
        } else {
            x.getParent().setLeftChild(y);
        }
    }

    x.setRightChild(x);
    x.setParent(y);
}
```

And here's the splay(Node x) method:

```
public void splay(Node<E> x) {
    while (x.getParent() != null) {
        if (x.isLeftChild && x.getParent().isLeftChild) {
            this.rightRotation(x.getParent());
            this.rightRotation(x);
        } else if (x.isRightChild && x.getParent().isRightChild) {
            this.leftRotation(x.getParent());
            this.leftRotation(x);
        } else if (x.isLeftChild && x.getParent().isRightChild) {
            this.rightRotation(x);
            this.leftRotation(x);
        } else if (x.isRightChild() && x.getParent().isLeftChild()) {
            this.leftRotation(x);
            this.rightRotation(x);
        } else if (x.isLeftChild && x.getParent() == root) {
            this.rightRotation(x);
        } else if (x.isRightChild && x.getParent() == root) {
            this.leftRotation(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix the infinite loop? It seems to be something to do with it not breaking out of the while(x.getParent() != null) statement in the splay(Node x) method, but when I went through the code using the debugger, the properties of the node seemed to be changing, so I don't really know where it's going wrong?

setLeftChild(Node leftChild) method:

```
public void setLeftChild(Node<E> leftChild) {
        this.leftChild = leftChild;

        if (leftChild != null) {
            leftChild.setIsRightChild(true);
            leftChild.setParent(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `splay` supposed to do ? Actually, what are all these methods supposed to do ?

Comment: It's a Binary Search Tree, leftRotation and rightRotation rotate the node up the tree towards the root, and splay is supposed to use those methods to balance the tree.

Comment: While I (and maybe other SO users) try to understand your code, please unit test your two methods to make sure they behave like you think they do. As a general rule, unit test is great

Comment: Can you show your `setLeftChild` method ? Looks like you would not need a `setParent` method if the setters were optimally implemented

Comment: Ok, so you set the parent in this method. It means you don't need your `if (y.getLeftChild() != null) {` in your first method, for example. BTW why do you do `leftChild.setIsRightChild(true)` whereas it's the left child ?

Comment: You should probably never be using `setParent` since methods `setLeft` and `setRight` do it for you... this complicates the code and is very likely to introduce inconsistencies

Comment: `x == x.getParent().getLeftChild()` is equivalent to `x.isLeftChild()`... there are many many things you can improve in this code both in terms of logic and readability. Fix all of this and your mistake should appear clearly

Comment: I add as many comments as bad things in your code, sorry, just to help. You don't need a boolean attribute to implement `isLeftChild`, you can just compare the value of the node to the value of the parent (if it exists)

Comment: In the first method, you don't disconnect `y`'s right child from `y` but you set it as the right child of `x`... Unless I'm mistaken, the output is not even a binary tree. The whole code is wrong, I'll stop there. May my comments help you to rewrite your code

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the mistakes/bad things I pointed out in your code, here is the biggest one, in `rightRotation` :

```
x.setRightChild(x);
```

This creates a cycle in your tree, hence the infinite loop. You should have unit tested your methods. One other major error in your code is that your `if - else if` instructions do not have an `else` so there might be cases where nothing happens during an iteration... hence the infinite loop. It's not the case here because you considered all the cases (actually, you considered even more, and the two last ones will never be executed because the four first cases cover every possible case) but as a general remark, this was really dangerous to code it that way.

Here is the code of my own implementation of all these methods, which I deem cleaner :

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private Node<T> root;

    public void rebalance(Node<T> node) {
        while (!node.isRoot()) rotation(node.getParent(), node.getChildKind().opposite());
    }

    private void rotation(Node<T> node, Side side) {
        if (node.getChild(side.opposite()) == null) return;

        Node<T> sideChild = node.getChild(side.opposite());
        node.setChild(sideChild.getChild(side), side.opposite());

        if (node.getParent() == null) setRoot(sideChild);
        else                          node.getParent().setChild(sideChild, node.getChildKind());

        sideChild.setChild(node, side);
    }

    private void setRoot(Node<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
        if (root != null) root.setRoot();
    }

    private static enum Side { 
        LEFT, RIGHT;

        public Side opposite() { return this == LEFT ? RIGHT : LEFT; }
    }

    private static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
        private T value;
        private Node<T> left, right, parent;

        public Node(T value) { this(value, null, null, null); } 

        public Node(T value, Node<T> left, Node<T> right, Node<T> parent) {
            setValue (value );
            setLeft  (left  );
            setRight (right );
            setParent(parent);
        }

        public Node<T> setLeft(Node<T> left) {
            this.left = left;
            if (left != null) left.parent = this;
            return this;
        }

        public Node<T> setRight(Node<T> right) {
            this.right = right;
            if (right != null) right.parent = this;
            return this;
        }

        public Node<T> setChild(Node<T> child, Side side) { return side == Side.LEFT ? setLeft(child) : setRight(child); }

        public Node<T> setRoot() { return setParent(null); }

        private Node<T> setParent(Node<T> parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
            return this;
        }

        public Node<T> setValue(T value) {
            this.value = notNull(value);
            return this;
        }

        public boolean isRoot() { return parent == null; }

        public boolean isLeftChild () { return isRoot() || getParent().getValue().compareTo(getValue()) > 0; }
        public boolean isRightChild() { return isRoot() || !isLeftChild()                                  ; }

        public Node<T> getChild(Side side) { return side == Side.LEFT ? getLeft() : getRight(); }

        public Side getChildKind() { 
            Check.isFalse(isRoot(), "This method is not defined on root nodes");
            return isLeftChild() ? Side.LEFT : Side.RIGHT; 
        }

        public T       getValue () { return value ; }
        public Node<T> getLeft  () { return left  ; }
        public Node<T> getRight () { return right ; }
        public Node<T> getParent() { return parent; }
    }
}
```

**Note :** my tree is not always optimally rebalanced. I did this out of my head but I will check at Wikipedia to see what they say, I probably did not apply the right algorithm, but it works pretty fine already expect in pathologic cases.